# Compilar arquivo C++ no VS Code usando o cmd externo

Tags: c, c++, cmd, visual-studio-code

Eu consigo compilar arquivos no VS Code normalmente, porém os arquivos são mostrados no terminal do propio programa , que não permite a inserção de caracteres. Como eu posso configurar para conseguir usar um terminal que me permita a interação?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como fez a compilação ? Está a usar alguma extensão ou inseriu o comando de compilação diretamente no terminal ?

Comment: Usei a extençao code runner. Queiro compilar diretamente no vs code com a possibilidade de interagir com o programa.

Comment: Só para informação, você não está usando o terminal, ali é janela de saída, a resposta do @vinicius-castro mostra como abrir o terminal

Answer (score 1):

Pressione Control + ' para abrir o terminal, e insira g++ -o nome_do_arquivo.cpp nome_do_arquivo_de_saida, vai ser gerado um executável. Certifique-se que você tem o g++ instalado.